# Count point when a specific button taped parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

Count point in a specific moment when button taped in a new column Parse for example :

```
    @IBAction func nbTapped(sender: AnyObject) {     
     let  PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("buttonpressed") as? Int (buttonpressed)! + 1
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be written as follows:

```
@IBAction func nbTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var count = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectForKey("buttonpressed")
    PFUser.currentUser()!["buttonpressed"] = count + 1
}
```

I'm not exactly Swift literate (Obj-C user), but that should work with minimal changes.